# "Waiting for Google BigQuery" error while connecting to Microsoft Power BI

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a few views created in Google BigQuery Project. I could connect all the GBQ data/views with my PBI till last week, but starting yesterday, I CAN NOT connect to 2 specific views from GBQ. It keeps on saying - "Waiting for GoogleBigQuery", and then nothing happens.

Can someone assist here? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing this answer from [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525061/11866133).

"I would not recommend using Power BI for Big Query analysis. As of Q1 2019 Power BI still do not support project billing unless manually editing the connexion script, it does not support Sheets federated tables, do not support nested and repeated fields and Power BI DML is nearly unusable with BQ. Microsoft do not seems to be willing to develop the compatibility between Power BI and Big Query further.

Learn more in this article (i am the author): https://medium.com/@remy_david/which-bi-tool-for-big-query-d9eb838ff7ad"

I asked the author for more details and I would recommend to read his medium article and wait for his advise.

Please be aware of the these [Considerations and Limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery#considerations-and-limitations)

I would update my answer with any additional findings regarding this issue.